# How do I print DBMS_UTILITY procedure results in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have tried several things, but this is the last.  This is in SQL Developer.  I've gotten errors over the various tries, but I do not know what to do.

```
declare
  jm varchar2;
begin
exec :jm := DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA('SCOTT','COMPUTE');
  dbms_output.put_line(jm);
end;
/
```

How do i view the ANALYZE_SCHEMA results in SQL Developer?  I have DBMS Output turned on and this works,

```
declare
  message varchar2(20):='hello johnny';
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(message);
end;
/
```

I also tried,

```
declare
  jm varchar2;
begin

  dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA('SCOTT','COMPUTE'));
end;
/
```

It says PLS-00222: no function with name 'ANALYZE_SCHEMA' exists in this scope.

Comment: `analyze_schema` gathers statistics on objects in the schema you provide as input. What do you mean by "view the results"? Do you want to see the statistics the procedure gathered and saved in system tables? By the way, you have "function" in your thread title, but this is a procedure, not a function.

Comment: No need for a PL/SQL block to begin with. `exec DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA('SCOTT','COMPUTE');` should work just fine. But that procedure does not have a "result" that can be viewed or displayed.

Comment: If there is no result I can see, then what do i use it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA` is a procedure, not function. In PL/SQL you cannot read the output from a procedure directly like function as there is no return value. The syntax to call a procedure from `sqldeveloper` / `sqlplus` is either

```
EXEC DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA('SCOTT','COMPUTE');
```

*OR*

```
BEGIN
DBMS_UTILITY.ANALYZE_SCHEMA('SCOTT','COMPUTE');
END;
```

The statistics of the analysis get updated in Oracle's data dictionaries and can be viewed by the following query(`owner = 'SCOTT'`) in your case

```
SELECT   owner, table_name, tablespace_name, num_rows, blocks, empty_blocks,
         avg_row_len, sample_size, last_analyzed
    FROM dba_tables
   WHERE UPPER (owner) = 'HR'
    ORDER BY owner, table_name;
```

**Sample Output**

```
OWNER     TABLE_NAME          TABLESPACE_NAME       NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS EMPTY_BLOCKS AVG_ROW_LEN SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANA
--------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ----------- ----------- --------
HR        REGIONS             USERS                        4          5            3          17           4 20-10-17
HR        TQ84_COMPARE        USERS                        3          5            3          11           3 20-10-17
HR        TT                  USERS                       10          5            3          22          10 20-10-17
```